# Loosing some values in perl script

Tags: perl

I have several hashes. Below have value

```
$data->{reports}->{$port}->{tb}->{tb});   
$data->{reports}->{$port}->{tb}->{change});   
$data->{reports}->{$port}->{tb_pbd}->{tb_pbd});
```

The values are:

```
$VAR1 = {   
'4|EXPENSES|Net Income' => '8658617.49'   
};   
$VAR1 = {   
'4|EXPENSES|Net Income' => '8728605.17'   
};   
$VAR1 = {
'4|EXPENSES|Net Income' => '-69987.68'   
};
```

separate variable has value:

```
$keyee       
value = 1|ASSETS|11240-000
```

However, when I put this value to all hash, for example:

```
$data->{reports}->{$port}->{tb}->{tb}->{$keyee}
```

It became undef. Any idea why and how to make treatment?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `$data->{reports}->{$port}->{tb}->{tb}` is a reference to a hash with one element. That element has the key  `4|EXPENSES|Net Income`, so if you try to access an element with a key of `1|ASSETS|11240-000` you will get `undef` because it doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

A hash key can hold only one value. To store multiple values associated with a single key , you need to use hash of array.

Code example :

```
my %myhash;
$myhash{'tb'}="val1";
$myhash{'tb'} ="vale2";
```

In the above example `tb` key will have only one value.

Now If you want to get both the values associated to the `tb` key use hash of array .
code example

```
push(@{$myhash},"val1");
push(@{$myhash},"val2");
```

Hope the above concept will help you.

For more information about hash of array visit : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch09_02.htm

Comment: That is interesting, but I have previous program for another database, and it  perfectly works. But new one - not. And in you case how can I check if it is defined? The same:(Defined ($data->{reports}->{$port}->{tb}->{tb}->{$keyee})?

Comment: you can check the key already exists or not using `exists $myhash{'tb'}`

Comment: But I have not only TB. I have report (they are different), port(portfolio - also different) and then tb and so on. How to check in this case?

Comment: when you are inserting a value associated with a key , just check using `if condition` that the key already exists or not .To check multiple values use **loop**.

Comment: I do next (If defined.....). But they not defined and I don't know how to make them work

Comment: use `exists`  to check the existence  of a variable instead defined